# How to display pixel art on a website?

Tags: website-design, pixel-art, subpixel-rendering

Pixel art of the sizes 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 px is too small in size (ranging from 100-500 Bytes). How do I display them properly scaled on a website?
for ex: cryptopunks website has punks which are 24x24 px and size ~ 200 Bytes, yet on the webpage they are very well displayed. When I do "open image in new tab" or download image, the image opened/downloaded is ~200bytes in size and of 24x24 px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you should upload your images as they are, let's say 64x64px, and rescale them using CSS.

```
<img src="face.png" class="scaleMe">

.scaleMe {width: 640px, height: 640px;}
```

Of course, this needs to be refined to be responsive. But that is the idea.

---

There are some CSS properties you can add, for example, use the image-rendering to decide if you want to smooth the edges. There is one pixelated... probably you should use that one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

But I am not sure if those properties are standard yet. https://caniuse.com/?search=image-rendering

[image]

---

I must say that this will only work if you have control over the website. If you are uploading it to a third-party webpage, you need to see the specification for the images. In that case, you probably need to resample them using nearest neibourg algorithm.

Comment: This seems like a good solution as I won't have to upscale each image and it will apply automatically to all images, but then again, will this rescaling using CSS have any kind of delay while loading webpages or cause any visible performance issues?

Comment: On the contrary. Loading a tiny png image is faster than a bigger image. The CSS instruction is also very lightweight.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rafael

Answer (score 0):

The images on the site you mentioned have been rescaled and resampled. You can use a raster image editor to do this.

In Photoshop do *Image > Image Size*, set resampling on, set to "Nearest neighbour", and enter a new larger size.

Or using GIMP (which is free), do *Image > Scale Image*, and set interpolation to "None", and enter a new size.

**An example below** using GIMP

Original 32x32px image on the left, rescaled to 200x200px image on the right.

[image]

Then you can export as a PNG image, and use it on your website

**Example**

[image]

Comment: I have a doubt, as you said "The images on the site you mentioned have been rescaled and resampled", but when I do "open image in new tab" or download image, the image opened/downloaded is ~200bytes in size and of 24x24 px. So are these images really upscaled? And, can this upscaling be done using some batch operation?

Comment: @SatyamSrivastava Sorry, I meant [this graphic here](https://www.larvalabs.com/public/images/product/cryptopunks/punk-variety-2x.png) which has been scaled. You're right, the individual ones seem to be rescaled in the browser.  Automation is possible in Photoshop using actions, GIMP would need a script. Possible also using ImageMagick which is command line based.  The example mushroom image above is still quite small at only 1.2kb, converting to Indexed Colour could help reduce it to around 880byes.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @Billy Kerr

Comment: @SatyamSrivastava Here's the css actually used in the site: **.pixelated {
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}**